# Taxonomy cache invalidate

Tags: 10

Drupal cache Drupal 10.

I'm trying to invalidate the cache, when there's a new taxonomy term is added.

Here's my code:

```
$build = [
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => ['taxonomy_list:city'],
    ]
];

return (new ResourceResponse($data, 200))->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build));
```

When I added a new city, the Cache is still HIT.  I want to refresh the cache when a new city is added to the taxonomy list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list cache tag, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags#syntax. And the entity machine name is `taxonomy_term`.

So the correct cache metadata could look like this:

```
$build = [
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => ['taxonomy_term_list:city'],
  ],
];
```

However, you still might need to add a cache context, in case the taxonomy query has dependencies like parts of the URL or the current user. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts